# Can someone please explain this block of Ruby code and why the variable is null inside the block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

```
2.0.0p247 :022 >   @post.title
 => "Breakfast Burrito"
2.0.0p247 :023 > solr = Refinery::Books::Book.search { fulltext @post.title.split(' ').join(' OR ') }
NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):23:in `block in irb_binding'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@bk_development/gems/sunspot-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/util.rb:208:in `instance_eval'
```

There's something I'm not picking up. FYI `fulltext` is a method not a hash, `search` takes a block, not a hash.

This works...

```
2.0.0p247 :026 >   solr = Refinery::Books::Book.search { fulltext 'burrito' }
  SOLR Request (13.9ms)  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block passed to `.search` may be evaluated in a different context with the help of [`BasicObject#instance_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) like (`instance_exec`, `class_eval`, `class_exec`) method, so that the method `fulltext` (and other DSL methods) defined for the receiver of `instance_eval`(maybe `Refinery::Books::Book`?) can be seen from the block. The magic here is Ruby changes the  `self` binding inside the block. The receiver of `instance_eval` acts as the `self` there.

Instance variable resolution also depends on `self`. When you refer to `@post`, you are actually fetching instance variable `@post` of `self`. Since the context of `self` has been modified in the block, and the actual `self` has no instance variable `@post`, `nil` is returned as the default value.

The fix is assign `@post.title` to a local variable and use that variable in the `.search` block.

```
title = @post.title
solr = Refinery::Books::Book.search { fulltext title.split(' ').join(' OR ') }
```

The block will capture the local binding at the place of its definition. In side the block, Ruby will first look up names in the local binding, and if missing, it will look up methods defined on `self`.